# how to implement cors on jersey2

Tags: cross-domain, cors, jersey-2.0

Since Jersey2 update context request/response API, it's impossible to use the 1.x way to set the value to header. Anyone know how to implement a filter or set some parameter to support cross domain/cros(Cross-origin resource sharing)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find it's better to use container to solve this kind of task.
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter_and_HttpServletRequest_attributes